# if table A value is not available in table B then select previous available value from table B

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to display all dates from Table A which are matching with dates from Table B. 
If Table A date is not available in Table B, then it should select the Previously available date.

For example,

I have table A as

```
Date1
"2017-04-10"
"2017-04-11"
"2017-04-12"
"2017-04-13"
"2017-04-14"
"2017-04-15"
"2017-04-16"
"2017-04-17"
"2017-04-18"
"2017-04-19"
"2017-04-20"
```

and table B as

```
Date2
"2017-04-10"
"2017-04-11"
"2017-04-12"
"2017-04-13"
"2017-04-18"
"2017-04-19"
"2017-04-20"
```

The result I am looking at is,

```
Date1        | NewDate
"2017-04-10" | "2017-04-10"
"2017-04-11" | "2017-04-11"
"2017-04-12" | "2017-04-12"
"2017-04-13" | "2017-04-13"
"2017-04-14" | "2017-04-13"
"2017-04-15" | "2017-04-13"
"2017-04-16" | "2017-04-13"
"2017-04-17" | "2017-04-13"
"2017-04-18" | "2017-04-18"
"2017-04-19" | "2017-04-19"
"2017-04-20" | "2017-04-20"
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses a lateral join or correlated subquery:

```
select a.*,
       (select b.date
        from b
        where b.date <= a.date
        order by b.date desc
        limit 1
       ) b
from a;
```

If you have a lot of data, then the following may be more efficient:

```
select a.date, b_date
from (select a.date,
             max(b_date) over (order by date, b_date) as b_date
      from ((select a.date as date, null as b_date
             from a
            ) union all
            (select b.date as date, b.date as b_date
             from b
            ) b
           ) ab
      ) ab
where b_date is not null;
```